# White Pixel in Raster (CIR) arcmap 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, orthophoto

i have to analyse forest cir orthophotos. in high scale resolution, many white pixel appear instead of red ones.
i work with arcmap 9.3, win7 [image]

Comment: What is your question?  Although we can make intelligent guesses, it is much better for you to be explicit about what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured it out by myself. It is because of the tiff compression: If it is jpeg, it has to be LZ77 or LZW. Any compression without data loss.

http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000020000000